# Incorrect datetime value: 'DEFAULT' using mysql in node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Using mysql 5.7 and node 12.

The table schema is like this

```
  name  varchar(255)   not null  primary key,
  createdAt  timestamp    default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null,
```

Now if i do

```
mysql> insert into myTable (name, createdAt) values ('name1', 'DEFAULT');
```

it works, but if i do

```
mysql> insert into myTable (name, createdAt) values ('name1', null);
```

it will say "cannot be null".

So i try to set the value to be DEFAULT if needed, go to my node code,

```
const addEntry (inputObj) => {
    const sqlCmd = `insert into myTable (name, createdAt)
           values ( ? ? )`;
    const param = ['name1', inputObj.createdAt || 'DEFAULT'];
    mysql.query(sqlCmd, param);
}
```

when i test it, don't define the createdAt property,
inputObj = { 'name': 'name1' };

it errors

```
Error:  ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'createdAt' at row 1
```

How to fix this please ?

Comment: When is the insert happening? During user's input? Or are you performing insert from another table?

Comment: this is straight forward insert, no other table.

Comment: i think i'll just build the sqlCmd and param based on if inputObj.createdAt is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a column that has both a `NOT NULL` constraint and a `DEFAULT` constraint.

You cannot assign a `NULL` value to that column because of the `NOT NULL` constraint, as you noticed: `NULL` is still considered a value.

If you want to benefit the `DEFAULT` constraint, you can either not assign a value to the column, or use expresssion `DEFAULT` (as a litteral, ie unquoted, else MySQL considers it as a string, which, as you would expect, cannot be assigned to a timestamp column):

```
insert into myTable (name) values ('name1');
insert into myTable (name, createdAt) values ('name1', DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Thx for the explanation, my real Q is: createdAt could be null, or could be a valid date from input, what's the best concise way to write in node ? don't want to use if/else.

Comment: @user3552178: I think you need some kind of if/else, one way or another. Why don’t you want to use if/else?